# To compile Swiss (standard) German in LaTeX?

Tags: languages

I want this letter

> â

but cannot find in German settings:

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{german}{babel}
\begin{document}
â 
\end{document}
```

**How can you compile correctly Swiss (standard) German language?**

Comment: Typo: `\usepackage{german}{babel}` should be `\usepackage[german]{babel}`. Then, your code works here using TeXlive 2014 on Linux.

Comment: @Sigur I'd also suggest using the language setting as a global option

Comment: @JosephWright How can you do this setting a global option?

Comment: @JosephWright I wouldn't suggest it.

Comment: @Masi - by specifying the option when executing `\documentclass`, i.e., as `\documentclass[german,...]{letter}`.

Comment: The most recent TeX distributions support the `swissgerman` and `nswissgerman` options.

Comment: @egreg: Why would’t you?

Comment: @Tobi See http://tug.org/pracjourn/2007-1/gregorio/gregorio.pdf, page 4. Unfortunately the paper is not in the final form I submitted, but that part is good. Things have changed with the most recent releases of `babel`, where you can specify `main=<lang>` in the options to `babel`.

Comment: @Masi: the letter ^a does not occur in German language (and can hardly imagine, that it's used in Swiss German)

Comment: @Masi: I meant does not occur in German alphabet ;-)

Comment: Are there any news here on this matter?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Is it used in German? The fact that it is not in the alphabet doesn't mean much. It isn't in the Welsh alphabet either, but it is certainly used when writing the Welsh language.

Comment: @cfr: Such letters do only occur in words from foreign languages (i.e. in this case non-German), if they are used in direct usage without explicit translation.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer OK. That's what I thought you must mean. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works without any problem:

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[nswissgerman]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

â

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If the issue is just obtaining the character, neither `hyperref` nor `babel` is required.

Comment: @cfr At least the settings for Swiss is important.

Comment: Only if you are typesetting Swiss German. Not just to obtain the â.

Comment: There is no Swiss language. Switzerland has four official languages. Swiss German is none of them. What you are relating to is Swiss high German.

Comment: @tanGIS Swiss German may not be the official name, but the language variety you read in newspapers and books published in Switzerland has some peculiarities that distinguish it from “standard German”, which warrant a specific language module for `babel`. There is also a specific ISO language code for it.

Comment: I do not understand why you rejected my edit. It's crystal clear in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swiss_German): *The dialects of Swiss German must not be confused with Swiss Standard German, the variety of Standard German used in Switzerland.*

Comment: @tanGIS I rejected nothing at all. But you're acknowledging that there exists Swiss standard German. I'm not sure what you're objecting about. Perhaps the “Swiss” I used in my comment? If so, that was just a shorthand, no pretense of using an official name. I can easily remove it, if you wish.

Comment: @egreg I am confused because someone rejected my edit and someone comments in the same way as my edit was targeting. Thus we seem to agree. I oppose to the usage of *Swiss* and *Swiss language* in the question (it's title). Even if you consider those as shorthands they would relate to *Swiss german*. But the question is about *Swiss Standard German*, sometimes also called *Swiss High German*.

Comment: @tanGIS The edit was to the question, not to my answer. I didn't get notified about it. I think that the question is not strictly about Swiss standard German, so possibly “Swiss German” could be a term that encompasses everything. Would  “Swiss (standard) German” be good, in your opinion?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110821/discussion-between-tangis-and-egreg).